# (node:93364) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

im currently following a youtube video which is using node.js to do some web scraping. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzZ3YOUhCxo&ab_channel=AaronJack)

ive managed to follow the tutorial and it works so i tried doing my own example and for some reason its failing and im not sure why.

i have attached the code below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrapeProduct(url){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="s7viewer_swatches_listbox"]/div[1]/div/div')
    const src = await el.getProperty('src')
    const image = await src.jsonValue()

    console.log({image})
    browser.close()
    }


scrapeProduct('https://groceries.asda.com/product/regular-cola/coca-cola-classic-bottle/1000020585281')
```

Comment: seems like it wasnt allowing scraping on that particular website. could that be a thing? 
i tried the code on a different website and it seemed to work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this warning is you are ignoring the case that Promise would be rejected. To handle it with `async/await` you can wrap your code in a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    const result = await Promise.reject(30); // you should replace it with your async function that may reject
}  catch (err) {
    // handle the error
}
```

In your case:

```
async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)

        const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="s7viewer_swatches_listbox"]/div[1]/div/div')
        const src = await el.getProperty('src')
        const image = await src.jsonValue()

        console.log({image})
        browser.close()
    } catch(err) {
        // handle the error
        console.log('error: ', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry how do i incorporate that into my code?

Comment: @hbk1414 update. If it helped you, please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Hi, the code itself worked as it closed down the code due to an error. but im still receiving the error message which is : 

error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined